# Fetch Data and Populate in Text Boxes if Selected Dropdown Option

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

**QUESTION UPDATED WITH CURRENT STATUS**

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I want to autofill my form textboxes with the values in database when i select dropdown option. i've been finding solution since days but didn't get any success. I'm very new at this.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO:**
I have two invoices `VendorInvoice` and `CustomerInvoice`…
I created my `VendorInvoice`, fill all data and store in `DB`…
But when i want to create `CustomerInvoice`, i need to fetch & autofill the same data which i filled and stored in `DB` for `VendorInvoice`.
So when i create `CustomerInvoice`, I have a `<select>` options of `VendorInvoice _no`, by selecting any option `CustomerInvoice` form fields should auto fill with the `VendorInvoice` & `VendorInvoiceItems` data.
So i don’t have to fill same data by myself again in `CustomerInvoice`…

**In my code:**

`VendorInvoice` = `ticketInvoice` && `VendorInvoiceItems` = `ticketInvoiceItems`
`CustomerInvoice` = `ctInvoice` && `CustomerInvoiceItems` = `ctInvoiceItems`

If anyone could help to get me out from this issue i'll be very grateful. Thank You.

**Here Is my `HTML` `<select>` & some `ctInvoice` & `ctInvoiceItems` fields which i want to autofill:**

```html
<form @submit.prevent="editmode ? updateCtInvoice() : createCtInvoice()">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- =====VENDOR INVOICE SELECTION===== -->
      <select id="ticket_invoice_no" v-model="selectedTicketInvoiceId" @change="getRecord" name="ticket_invoice_no" type="text" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="ticketInvoice in ticketInvoices" :key="ticketInvoice.id" :value="ticketInvoice.id">{{ ticketInvoice.ticket_invoice_no }}</option>
      </select>

      <!-- =====CUSTOMER TICKET INVOICE NUMBER===== -->
      <input v-model="form.ct_invoice_no" type="text" name="ct_invoice_no" class="form-control">

      <!-- =====CUSTOMER TICKET INVOICE ITEMS===== -->
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(ctInvoiceItem, key) in form.ctInvoiceItems" :key="key">
          <!--Passenger Name-->
          <td>
            <input v-model="ctInvoiceItem.ct_passenger_name" size="40" type="text" name="ct_passenger_name" class="table-control form-control">
          </td>

          <!--Ticket No.-->
          <td>
            <input v-model="ctInvoiceItem.ct_ticket_no" size="24" type="text" name="ct_ticket_no" class="table-control form-control">
          </td>

          <!--Flight No.-->
          <td>
            <input v-model="ctInvoiceItem.ct_flight_no" size="7" type="text" name="ct_flight_no" class="table-control form-control">
          </td>
      </tbody>
```

**My `@change="getRecord"` method:**

```js
getRecord: function(e) {
  axios
    .get("api/ticket-invoice/fetch/" + this.selectedTicketInvoiceId)
    .then(({
      data
    }) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.form = data; // assumes the data keys maps directly to the form properties!!
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
}
```

**Route:**

```js
Route::get('ticket-invoice/fetch/{ticket_invoice}', 'API\TicketInvoiceController@fetch')->name('ticket-invoice.fetch');
```

**My `fetch(){}` method:**

```js
public function fetch($id) {
  $ticketInvoices = TicketInvoice::findOrFail($id);

  return response() ->json([
    'id' => '',
    'customer_id' => '',
    'ct_invoice_no' => $ticketInvoices->ticket_invoice_no,
    'ct_invoice_date' => $ticketInvoices->ticket_invoice_date,
    'ct_invoice_fares_total' => $ticketInvoices->ticket_invoice_fares_total,
    'ct_invoice_grand_total' => $ticketInvoices->ticket_invoice_grand_total,
    'ctInvoiceItems' => $ticketInvoices->ticketInvoiceItems->map(function($item) {
      return [
        // get the relevant $item->property for each key below
        'id' => "",
        'ct_invoice_id' => "",
        'ct_passenger_name' => $item->passenger_name,
        'ct_fares' => $item->fares,
        'ct_sub_total' => $item->sub_total
      ];
    }) ->all()
  ]);
}
```

**My `data()` in Vue Component:**

```js
data() {
  return {
    editmode: true,
    selectedTicketInvoiceId: false,
    ticketInvoices: {},
    ctInvoices: {},
    customers: null,
    form: new Form({
      id: "",
      customer_id: "",
      ct_invoice_no: "",
      ct_invoice_date: "",
      ct_invoice_fares_total: 0,
      ct_invoice_grand_total: 0,

      ctInvoiceItems: [{
        id: "",
        ct_invoice_id: "",
        ct_passenger_name: "",
        ct_fares: 0,
        ct_sub_total: 0
      }]
    })
  };
},
```

When i select option i see in my Vue Component that specific `id` data fill in my `form:`. but its not actually fill my input fields with that data, so i could do some changes in the data and finally store it in `DB` as a `customerInvoice`.

**`Vue Dev Tool` BEFORE SELECTING OPTION:**
[image]

**`Vue Dev Tool` AFTER SELECTING OPTION:**
[image]

**BUT NOT FILLING FIELDS:**
[image]

Comment: Question Updated With Current Status

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Laravel 5.7 or vue but the concept remains the same

1- I would give an example of what I would do, I'll make a php file that has a select * from database and echo the result in json
 2- Then use ajax, fetch to the php file and get that json, I will use the data retrieved in the javascript file
 3 - I will have a function like on Dropdown Option onclick fetch or ajax, make the dropdown options equal to to the json fetched.

Comment: i've seen many examples for PHP, but it didn't get me to my destination,, just because i'm working on Vue Components. BTW i appreciate your support, you could see my updates: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/fetch-data-and-populate-in-text-boxes-if-selected-dropdown-option